# Ionic: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

That error occur in a .factory function. In my project I have 2 `.factory` that both used each other. Below is my controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Factory_A) {
  $scope.do = function(){
      Factory_A.do_A();
  };
})
```

*Scenario 1:*

```
.factory('Factory_A', function(Factory_B){

  var value_A = 1;

  return{
    do_A: function(){
      if(value_A == 1){
        value_A++;
        Factory_B.do_B();
      }

      else{
        return "Success"
      }
    }
  }

})

.factory('Factory_B', function(Factory_A){

    var value_B = 0;

    var do_B_1 = function(){
      Factory_A.do_A();
    };

    return{
      do_B: function(){
        value_B++;

        if(value_B > 0){
          do_B_1();
        }

        return true;
      }
  }
});
```

**Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: Factory_A <- Factory_B <- Factory_A**

*Scenario 2:*

```
.factory('Factory_A', function(){

  var value_A = 1;

  return{
    do_A: function(){
      if(value_A == 1){
        value_A++;
        Factory_B.do_B();
      }

      else{
        return "Success"
      }
    }
  }

})

.factory('Factory_B', function(Factory_A){

    var value_B = 0;

    var do_B_1 = function(){
      Factory_A.do_A();
    };

    return{
      do_B: function(){
        value_B++;

        if(value_B > 0){
          do_B_1();
        }

        return true;
      }
  }
});
```

**Error: Factory_B is not defined**

*Scenario 3:*

```
.factory('Factory_A', function(Factory_B){

  var value_A = 1;

  return{
    do_A: function(){
      if(value_A == 1){
        value_A++;
        Factory_B.do_B();
      }

      else{
        return "Success"
      }
    }
  }

})

.factory('Factory_B', function(){

    var value_B = 0;

    var do_B_1 = function(){
      Factory_A.do_A();
    };

    return{
      do_B: function(){
        value_B++;

        if(value_B > 0){
          do_B_1();
        }

        return true;
      }
  }
});
```

**Error: Factory_A is not defined**

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/NRzLYA) for **Scenario 3** shows how I simulate my project flow using a factory. Thanks.

Comment: So... what is the question? Just don't create services that depend on each other. It isn't obvious what are A and B and why they should use each others' methods. There's already a bunch of answered questions on this topic on SO, and the number of possible solutions is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$injector` to inject dependency runtime on self or circular dependency.

#### Full example code

Change you `js` in your demo page

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Factory_A) {
  $scope.do = function(){
      Factory_A.do_A();
  };
})

.factory('Factory_A', function($injector){

  var value_A = 1;

  return{
    do_A: function(){
      if(value_A == 1){
        value_A++;
        var Factory_B = $injector.get('Factory_B');
        Factory_B.do_B();
      }

      else{
        return "Success"
      }
    }
  }

})

.factory('Factory_B', function($injector){


    var value_B = 0;

    var do_B_1 = function(){
      var Factory_A = $injector.get('Factory_A');
      Factory_A.do_A();
    };

    return{
      do_B: function(){
        value_B++;

        if(value_B > 0){
          do_B_1();
        }

        return true;
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is actually what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking how to avoid the circular dependency.

In cases like these you might inject the `$injector` instead.  And then when calling the methods inside each factory, you inject them at that time **or** cache them after the first use.

```
.factory( 'FactoryA', function($injector){
     return {
         funcFoo: function(){
              var fb = $injecto.get('FactoryB')
              fb.funcBar()
         }

     }
})

.factory( 'FactoryB', function($injector){
     return {
         funcFoo: function(){
              var fa = $injecto.get('FactoryA')
              fa.funcFoo()
         }

     }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jusopi . This is actually what I want.